# Timezone in timestamps imported from csv

Tags: r, csv, datetime, posixct, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a dataframe imported with `fread` from a csv file (converted from .xlsx). After import, `class(inputData$timestamp)` is `Posixct` and `attr(inputData$timestamp, "tzone")` is `""`.

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852641/in-r-how-can-i-split-a-dataframe-by-date) thread, I'm trying to split the dataframes by day, but they get split at 2am:

```
byDay <- split(inputData, as.Date(inputData$timestamp))
> byDay[[1]]
              timestamp value
1   2016-09-05 00:01:00     0
2   2016-09-05 00:02:00     0
3   2016-09-05 00:03:00     0
[...]
118 2016-09-05 01:58:00     0
119 2016-09-05 01:59:00     0

>byDay[[2]]
              timestamp value
120 2016-09-05 02:00:00     0
121 2016-09-05 02:01:00     0
122 2016-09-05 02:02:00     0
[...]
1558 2016-09-06 01:58:00    0
1559 2016-09-06 01:59:00    0
```

and so on.

I understand the date is implicitly different from what's shown on the timestamp:

```
> byDay[[1]]$timestamp[1]
"2016-09-05 00:01:00"
> as.Date(byDay[[1]]$timestamp[1])
"2016-09-04"
```

I'm not interested in timezones so I tried just setting all dates to UTC:

```
> attr(inputData$timestamp, "tzone") <- "UTC"
> byDay <- split(inputData, as.Date(inputData$timestamp))
> byDay[[1]]
              timestamp apAvg
1   2016-09-04 22:01:00     0
2   2016-09-04 22:02:00     0
3   2016-09-04 22:03:00     0
[...]
117 2016-09-04 23:57:00     0
118 2016-09-04 23:58:00     0
119 2016-09-04 23:59:00     0
```

This implies the timestamps actually start at 22:00. However in the csv file, the first timestamp is `05.09.2016 00:00:00` and I can't see a sign of timezone formatting. 
Is there still a possibility that the timezone problems come from the csv file?
Or do I handle the timestamps wrong in R? 
How to deal with this accurately?

Comment: This is something you should really address when you're parsing from string to POSIXct, not after the fact, or it gets very ambiguous whether you're changing the time zone (i.e. adjusting the hours too) or just switching it (i.e. changing the data). Instead specify `tz` in `as.POSIXct` or whatever parsing function you're using.

Comment: See [mcve] on how to ask a question on SO.  Show the output of `dput(X)` if your input (or a cut down version of it) is X.

Comment: @alistaire Setting `tz = ""` in `as.POSIXct` solved it. Also more consistent approach to get the timezone right when parsing instead of later on. Thanks.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for reminding. However I cannot post a csv file here, so I wouldn't know how to provide sample input for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Show the output of `dput(InputData)` or `dput(head(InputData))` if sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow @alistaire's advice in setting the time zone when parsing from string. In fact, this appears to have happened since

> `attr(inputData$timestamp, "tzone")` is `""`

afterwards and `""` is the default to set the data to your local timezone.

The issue is that in using `as.Date` with a class `POSIXct` input, the default for `tz` is `"UTC"` and not your local timezone. To get what you want:

1. **Do not** change the data's timezone to `"UTC"`
2. Use `as.Date(inputData$timestamp, tz="")` in your `split`.

To illustrate, let's say the data is:

```
inputData<- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1473048000, 1473051600, 
1473055200, 1473058800, 1473062400, 1473066000, 1473069600, 1473073200, 
1473076800, 1473080400, 1473084000, 1473087600, 1473091200, 1473094800, 
1473098400, 1473102000, 1473105600, 1473109200, 1473112800, 1473116400, 
1473120000, 1473123600, 1473127200, 1473130800, 1473134400, 1473134460, 
1473134520, 1473134580), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), .Names = c("timestamp", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = "data.frame")
##             timestamp value
##1  2016-09-05 00:00:00     0
##2  2016-09-05 01:00:00     0
##3  2016-09-05 02:00:00     0
##4  2016-09-05 03:00:00     0
##5  2016-09-05 04:00:00     0
##6  2016-09-05 05:00:00     0
##7  2016-09-05 06:00:00     0
##8  2016-09-05 07:00:00     0
##9  2016-09-05 08:00:00     0
##10 2016-09-05 09:00:00     0
##11 2016-09-05 10:00:00     0
##12 2016-09-05 11:00:00     0
##13 2016-09-05 12:00:00     0
##14 2016-09-05 13:00:00     0
##15 2016-09-05 14:00:00     0
##16 2016-09-05 15:00:00     0
##17 2016-09-05 16:00:00     0
##18 2016-09-05 17:00:00     0
##19 2016-09-05 18:00:00     0
##20 2016-09-05 19:00:00     0
##21 2016-09-05 20:00:00     0
##22 2016-09-05 21:00:00     0
##23 2016-09-05 22:00:00     0
##24 2016-09-05 23:00:00     0
##25 2016-09-06 00:00:00     0
##26 2016-09-06 00:01:00     0
##27 2016-09-06 00:02:00     0
##28 2016-09-06 00:03:00     0
```

with:

```
attr(inputData$timestamp, "tzone")
##[1] ""
```

Doing your `split` using `as.Date` with the default `tz` parameter:

```
byDay <- split(inputData, as.Date(inputData$timestamp))
byDay[[1]]
##             timestamp value
##1  2016-09-05 00:00:00     0
##2  2016-09-05 01:00:00     0
##3  2016-09-05 02:00:00     0
##4  2016-09-05 03:00:00     0
## ...
##17 2016-09-05 16:00:00     0
##18 2016-09-05 17:00:00     0
##19 2016-09-05 18:00:00     0
##20 2016-09-05 19:00:00     0
byDay[[2]]
##             timestamp value
##21 2016-09-05 20:00:00     0
##22 2016-09-05 21:00:00     0
##23 2016-09-05 22:00:00     0
##24 2016-09-05 23:00:00     0
##25 2016-09-06 00:00:00     0
##26 2016-09-06 00:01:00     0
##27 2016-09-06 00:02:00     0
##28 2016-09-06 00:03:00     0
```

Now, I'm on the east coast of the United States so I'm on EDT now. This is why `22:00:00` here is `split` to the next day in UTC. Do the same `split` with `as.Date(inputData$timestamp,tz="")`:

```
byDay <- split(inputData, as.Date(inputData$timestamp,tz=""))
byDay[[1]]
##             timestamp value
##1  2016-09-05 00:00:00     0
##2  2016-09-05 01:00:00     0
##3  2016-09-05 02:00:00     0
##4  2016-09-05 03:00:00     0
## ...
##21 2016-09-05 20:00:00     0
##22 2016-09-05 21:00:00     0
##23 2016-09-05 22:00:00     0
##24 2016-09-05 23:00:00     0
byDay[[2]]
##             timestamp value
##25 2016-09-06 00:00:00     0
##26 2016-09-06 00:01:00     0
##27 2016-09-06 00:02:00     0
##28 2016-09-06 00:03:00     0
```

Comment: I used @alistaire's approach, still helpful answer.